# php replace string to html tag

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

I want to display content in a php page from a .txt and change some tag to a html code like the following using:

**Change this:**

```
[img: something.jpg]
```

**To this:**

```
<img src="something.jpg" />
```

I've tried to use `preg_replace`, but I have no idea how to use those symbols like `/(){}^*.:`.
What it means to use things like this to extract some variables `$1 $2` from a string?

```
$string = 'April 15, 2003';
$pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/i';
```

Comment: `echo preg_replace("/\[img:\s*([^\]]+)\]/i","<img src='$1'>",$string)`

Comment: https://eval.in/473133

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex like as

```
\[(\w+):\s?(\w+.\w+)]
```

**Regex Explanation**

- `\[` : `\[` will check for `[` literally.
- `(\w+):` : `(\w+)` Capturing groups of any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, `:` will check for `:` literally
- `\s?` : match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`. `?` Between zero and one time, as many times as possible
- `(\w+.\w+)` : Capturing group of any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

So using `preg_replace` like as

```
echo preg_replace('/\[(\w+):\s?(\w+.\w+)]/',"<$1 src='$2' />","[img: something.jpg]");
```

[**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/kS2hS1/1)

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/ZEElq)

Comment: But OP didn't defined any of those scenarios @Starkeen. If OP identify any of these scenario I'll update as per required.

Answer (score 2):

@Uchiha has a great regex *(+1 for it!)*, but you may want to use a `preg_replace_callback()` instead if you are wanting to use it for a `[shortcode]` type application:

```
function shortcode($val = false)
    {
        return (!empty($val))? preg_replace_callback('/\[(\w+):\s?(\w+.\w+)]/',function($matches) {
                if(!empty($matches[2])) {
                        switch($matches[1]) {
                                case ('img'):
                                    return '<img src="'.$matches[2].'" />';
                            }
                    }
            },$val) : false;
    }

echo shortcode('[img: something.jpg]');
```

Comment: That dot is an any character rather than a literal dot.